# Concatenar Hora y minutos en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2012

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
CONVERT(TIME,convert(varchar,F.T2InHour)+convert(varchar,F.T2InMinute),108)
```

lo que quiero es lo siguiente en `F.T2InHour` Tengo la Hora y En `F.T2InMinute` tengo los minutos, quiero unirlos y que me salga la hora y los minutos Ejemplo ASi 8:30:00

Comment: Esto te puede funcionar select SUBSTRING( CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 113),12,9)

Comment: @hllberes lo que pasa que en las tablas que te mencione tengo en una la hora y en otra los minutos

Comment: T2InHour y T2InMinute son datetime?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no son de tipo int

Comment: Bien, y T2InMinute solo tiene valores de 0 a 59?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Exacto

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Eso son los valores que tiene pero el campo es tipo int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, 
                 LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + F.T2InHour),2) + ':' +
                 LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 100 + F.T2InMinute),2) + ':00'
              )
       FROM ....
```

Simplemente formateamos una cadena como `hh:mm:00` y luego la convertimos en un dato `TIME`.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta de los campos que te mencione antes tengo un campo que me almacena el numero de la semana del 0 al 6 quisiera saber como valido esta opcion utilizando la funcion weekday

Comment: A que te refieres con validar? `weekday` no es una función de SQL Server, no será `datepart`?. Te sugiero que armes otra pregunta. Saludos